# Dynamically define a RETURN table (column type, name) for subsequent loop

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, postgis

I would like to execute `ST_Intersection(clipper_geom, clipped_geom)` on number of rows coming from a table.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html

POSTGIS intersection does not support the processing of multiple geometries natively, differently from `ST_Intersects()` and I had to design a function (returning a table) that selects rows intersecting with my `clipper_geom` using `ST_Intersects()`, loop through the result set and compute each intersection with `ST_Intersection()`. The `geom` field and `clipped_geom_wkt` are the ones recording the clipped geometry.

The function works, but I need a different one for every table we want to produce the clipping. I would like to read the input table dynamically (column name and type) and define both in the `RETURN` statement.

All field names and types are the same, only `geom` is updated and `clipped_geom_wkt` is added.

I tried to search Stack Overflow and I found examples on how to create dynamic table structure but none performs a subsequent `LOOP` over the first results, where the column names have to be matched to insert / update the new data.

This is what I have come up so far, but I am unsure about how to perform the `LOOP` part, to add the `clipped_geom_wkt` field and update the `geom` field. Some responses advise to use `RETURNS TABLE (...)` if more fields are added to `SETOF` ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821482/easy-way-to-have-return-type-be-setof-table-plus-additional-fields

But then it seems that dynamically generated columns are only supported with `RETURNS SETOF ...`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clip_palin_polygon_complete(clipped_table text,clipper_geom text, age_sequence VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (rec clipped_table, clipped_geom_wkt text)) AS $$ --not sure if this is the right way to do it...
DECLARE var_r record;
BEGIN
    FOR var_r IN (
        SELECT * FROM clipped_table 
        WHERE clipped_table.seq IN (age_sequence)
        AND ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom,4326), clipped_table.geom)
    )
    LOOP
        /* 
        these are the original table fields that I would like to keep and match
        dynamically with any table I have as input (clipped_table)
        objectid := var_r.objectid;
        seq := var_r.seq;
        -- etc.
        */

        --below there are the only two fields that need modifying
        geom := (
            SELECT ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom, 4326), var_r.geom) AS geom);
        clipped_geom_wkt := (
            SELECT
            ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom,4326), var_r.geom)) AS clipped_geom_wkt);
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: It would help to clarify your setup: Postgres version, PostGIS version, table definition (minimum example), desired result (for the example). You write `The function works`, but that can't be the displayed function, which certainly doesn't. Show your working function, describe how you want to change / expand it. You write `All fields names and types are the same`. The same between function input and output, or the same over all possible input tables? Seems you are trying to derive a return type dynamically from variable tables, plus one additional column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What you might need

You should be able to avoid all the complication with a simple `SELECT` instead:

```
SELECT t.*, ST_Intersection(x.geom, t.geom) AS geom2
FROM   tbl t  -- replace tbl with actual table
JOIN   ST_GeomFromText($clipper_geom, 4326) AS x(geom) ON ST_Intersects(x.geom, t.geom)
WHERE  t.seq = $age_sequence;
```

Minor difference: you get the original `geom` *and* the intersection `geom2` in the result. Add the redundant `ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(x.geom, t.geom)) AS clipped_geom_wkt` to the `SELECT` list if you really need it.

### What you ask

I understand your question like this:

*I have various input tables, each has a column `geom geometry`. I want a function to take a table name and `clipper_geom geometry` as input and return all rows intersecting with my `clipper_geom`. One column `clipped_geom_wkt text` shall be appended and the value of `geom` changed, each showing the intersection with `clipper_geom`.*

That's not trivial. SQL is a static language, a function demands to know the return type at call time *at the latest*. We can achieve dynamic results with polymorphic types, but we need a well-known row type to work with. The row type of an existing table is good for it, but you want to append another column. That's not easily possible. The workaround is to return the polymorphic row type, *plus* an extra column (like you seem to have tried already). Decompose the row type in the function call to arrive at your desired result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(_tbl ANYELEMENT
                                 , _clipper_geom text
                                 , _age_sequence text)
  RETURNS TABLE (tbl ANYELEMENT, clipped_geom_wkt text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _geom geometry := ST_GeomFromText(_clipper_geom, 4326);  -- compute once
BEGIN
   FOR tbl IN EXECUTE format(
     'SELECT * FROM %s
      WHERE  seq = $1
      AND    ST_Intersects($2, geom)'
    , pg_typeof(_tbl)
      )
   USING _age_sequence, _geom  -- data types must match!
   LOOP          
      tbl := json_populate_record(tbl, json_build_object('geom', ST_Intersection(_geom, tbl.geom)));
      clipped_geom_wkt := ST_AsText(tbl.geom);
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT (tbl).*, clipped_geom_wkt
FROM my_func(NULL::public.clipped_table, $my_clipper_geom, $my_age_sequence);
```

Works for me in Postgres 10.

##### Notable features

- Polymorphic types.
  Note how the row variable `tbl` is defined implicitly in the `RETURNS` clause, where it copies the input type dynamically (`ANYELEMENT`). So you are not bound to use `SETOF` with polymorphic types like you speculated.
  Related (you linked to that one yourself):

  - [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)
- [`FOR-IN-EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) to loop over a dynamic query.
- Assignment of a yet-unknown column with `json_populate_record()`. See:

  - [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860)
- Decomposing composite type in the function call with `(tbl).*`

#### Simpler

I stuck to your design above, but it's unnecessary complication for the given example. The extra column `clipped_geom_wkt` is completely redundant, just derive it from `geom` in the function call. Then we can use the input type directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func2(_tbl ANYELEMENT
                                  , _clipper_geom text
                                  , _age_sequence text)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYELEMENT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _geom geometry := ST_GeomFromText(_clipper_geom, 4326);
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN EXECUTE format(
     'SELECT * FROM %s
      WHERE  seq = $1
      AND    ST_Intersects($2, geom)'
    , pg_typeof(_tbl)
      )
   USING _age_sequence, _geom  -- data types must match!
   LOOP
      _tbl := json_populate_record(_tbl, json_build_object('geom', ST_Intersection(_geom, _tbl.geom)));
      RETURN NEXT _tbl;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(geom) AS clipped_geom_wkt  -- if you need the redundant column
FROM   my_func2(NULL::public.clipped_table, $my_clipper_geom, $my_age_sequence);
```

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge the approach of creating a function it was over complicating the solution to the problem, but as non-expert in SQL it looked simpler to me to understand. The answer solved my problem and went beyond explaining how to achieve a solution using the same methodology I wanted to use. Thanks a lot. On a side note, I need indeed the WKT representation of the clipped geometries as they are later outputted to another software component which is unable to understand Postgis geom type.